# Python Set not Detecting Duplicate Node

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, set, nodes

I have created a `Graph` class along with a `Node` class that I've tested. It is working with basic tests. I'm now trying to test with a custom input file and I'm running into an error where some of the `Node`s are being duplicated. In the `Graph` class, there is a set called `Nodes` where the `Node` being created is added. However, in my parser file I have a checker which checks to see if the Node with the value has been added before but it's not working properly.
Even after adding in the hash function below, I still get `set([Alpha, Beta, Hotel, Alpha])`.
What am I doing wrong?

Test File:

```
directed unweighted
Alpha=Hotel
Alpha=Beta
Beta=Charlie
Charlie=Juliett
Charlie=Juliett
Delta=Foxtrot
Delta=Golf
Echo=Charlie
Echo=Delta
Foxtrot=Golf
Golf=Juliett
Golf=Alpha
Hotel=Echo
Hotel=India
India=Beta
India=Golf
Juliett=Golf
```

Graph and Node Class:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Nodes = set()

    def addVertex(self, vertex):
        self.Nodes.add(vertex)
    
    def getVertices(self):
        return self.Nodes


    @staticmethod
    def addEdgeDirect(fromEdge, toEdge, cost=1):
        fromEdge.neighbors[toEdge] = cost


class Node():
    def __init__(self, val = None):
        self.value = val
        self.neighbors = {}

    def getEdges(self):
        return self.neighbors.keys()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
```

Test File Parser:

```
from graph import Graph, Node

graph = Graph()

file1 = open('Graphs/du.gl', 'r')
Lines = file1.readlines()

direction = Lines[0].split(" ")[0].strip()
weight = Lines[0].split(" ")[1].strip() 

count = 0
if(direction == "directed"):
    if(weight == "unweighted"):
        for line in Lines:
            count += 1
            if(count == 1):
                continue
            node1 = Node(line.split("=")[0].strip())
            node2 = Node(line.split("=")[1].strip())
            if node1 not in graph.Nodes:
                print("not found, to be added")
                graph.addVertex(Node(node1))

            if node2 not in graph.Nodes:
                graph.addVertex(Node(node2))    

            print(graph.getVertices())
            graph.addEdgeDirect(node1,node2)
            # print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

Comment: Your node class needs to define a __ hash __ method

Comment: Most languages have a concept of Hashable and Equatable. A simple explanantion for Python: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-oop/python-__hash__/

Comment: *"but it's not working properly"*: that is not a good problem description. Please provide the output you expect, and the output you get, and what is different.

Comment: @trincot I'm expecting a unique set of values however I'm not getting that, after adding in the __hash__ function below, I still get set([Alpha, Beta, Hotel, Alpha])

Comment: I believe the problem is with my "not in graph.Nodes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `set` objects are always distinguished by their object ID (reference). So it doesn't help to define `__hash__` either.

I would suggest to:

- Use a dictionary instead of a set
- Only create `Node` instances when you already know that you need a new instance -- so after having checked that the `Nodes` dictionary doesn't have it yet
- By consequence: pass the string value to `addVertex` instead of a `Node` instance.

With some other little changes, your code could be:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = {}

    def addVertex(self, key):
        if key not in self.nodes:
            self.nodes[key] = Node(key)
        return self.nodes[key]
    
    def getVertices(self):
        return self.nodes.values()

    @staticmethod
    def addEdgeDirect(fromEdge, toEdge, cost=1):
        fromEdge.neighbors[toEdge] = cost


class Node():
    def __init__(self, val=None):
        self.value = val
        self.neighbors = {}

    def getEdges(self):
        return self.neighbors.keys()
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)
    

graph = Graph()
file1 = open('du.gl', 'r')
firstline, *lines = file1.readlines()
direction, weight = firstline.split()
if direction == "directed":
    if weight == "unweighted":
        for line in lines:
            graph.addEdgeDirect(*(graph.addVertex(key.strip()) 
                                  for key in line.split("=")))
            print(graph.getVertices())
```

### Addendum

In comments you ask about `getEdges` and how it could return more information.

Here is a variant of that method:

```
def getEdges(self):
    return { self: self.neighbors }
```

If you then do this:

```
print(graph.nodes['Alpha'].getEdges())
```

...it will output:

```
{Alpha: {Hotel: 1, Beta: 1}}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does create a unique set however, if you tried to run the getEdges() function, it still reads the Nodes as unique Nodes and doesn't create a dictionary with multiple keys. For example, Alpha is connected to Beta and Hotel however it outputs like: Alpha {Hotel: 1} Alpha {Beta: 1} instead of [Alpha: {Hotel:1}, {Beta:1}]

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. What exactly are you executing to output this? Need to look at this... When I output `graph.nodes['Alpha'].getEdges()` I get `[Hotel, Beta]`. Is that not expected?

Comment: The getEdges function returns the Nodes it's pointed to since it's directed however there is only one edge being shown even though there should be more than one

Comment: What do you mean with "shown"? Which code are you referring to? The `neighbors` collection for "Alpha" has two entries, so I am at a loss what you mean...

Comment: The neighbors should contain multiple entries since what I'm trying to do with it is have a Node's connected neighbors inside it unless there's only one neighbor. In the case with Alpha, we can see it's connected to hotel and beta

Comment: What do you mean "we can see it's connected". I can see it. I don't see the problem. Can you please tell me in Python syntax what you expect `graph.nodes['Alpha'].getEdges()` to return?

Comment: It should return:  [Alpha: {Hotel:1}, {Beta:1}]

Comment: That is not valid Python. I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Sorry, I think it's formatted like this: Alpha:[{Hotel:1},{Beta:1}]

Comment: Where Hotel and Beta are the edges Alpha connects to (and the 1 is the default weight which we don't have to worry about)

Comment: Can you please first check in a Python console to make sure this expression is valid? It currently is not correct syntax. I really don't know what you want, and of course I cannot make that code return something that is not valid Python. I just did what you had in your code where you returned a *list*.

Comment: Putting the print(fromEdge.neighbors) after fromEdge.neighbors[toEdge] = cost, causes an output like this: {Hotel: 1}
{Beta: 1}
{Charlie: 1}
{Juliett: 1}
{Juliett: 1}
{Foxtrot: 1}
{Golf: 1}
{Charlie: 1}
{Delta: 1}
{Golf: 1}
{Juliett: 1}
{Alpha: 1}
{Echo: 1}
{India: 1}
{Beta: 1}
{Golf: 1}
{Golf: 1}

Comment: Putting the print(fromEdge.neighbors) before the fromEdge.neighbors[toEdge] = cost, causes the output like this: 
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}
{}

Comment: Please.... I just need the **data structure** notation of what `getEdges` should return for `graph.nodes['Alpha'].getEdges()`. Valid Python. Not a print output... The data structure. That shouldn't be too hard. I only have 15 minutes left before being offline for 8 hours.

Comment: It should be a list of objects like this {'Alpha': [{Hotel:1}, {Beta:1}]}

I'm sorry if this is unclear... It does not have to be in any specific format, it just needs to show that Alpha is connected to Hotel and Beta

Comment: So you want to return a dictionary? That is not what you were doing in your code. Your function was returning a list, not a dictionary. It seems you are extending the question to other things.

Comment: Either one works for me, I just don't know why I can't show that Alpha is connected to more than one edge

Comment: See section I added to my answer, but this really should have been a separate question. I have to go now.

Answer (score 1):

You are expecting that the set should contain nodes with unique names, but nowhere do you specify that uniqueness should depend on the property `value` of those nodes.

You should add the following method to your node class:

```py
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.value)
```

Comment: If you run my code after adding that I still get: set([Alpha, Beta, Hotel, Alpha])
which means Alpha is being added in twice as two different Nodes instead of the same

Comment: @AngelaRubchinksy My bad, I forgot about `__eq__` as well, see @kcsquared answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues, some related to a lack of type checking and some from the design of your class.

First, you have a `Node` class, instances of which you've kind of implied maybe should have a unique `self.value`, and that `self.value` is expected to always be a string (although these expectations are not contained in the code).

One problem causing the `set()` behavior, addressed in another comment, is the lack of a `__hash__()` method. Since it seems like you maybe want two Nodes to be equal if and only if their `value` parameter is the same string, adding

```py
def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.value)
```

is needed. However, for `set()` to work like you want, you also need to add an `__eq__()` function.

```py
def __eq__(self, other):
    return isinstance(other, Node) and self.value == other.value
```

It's unclear to me whether the 'neighbors' attribute of a node should matter for its identity, as the terms `node` and `graph` don't carry information about what the classes actually are or represent, so maybe `neighbors` should be included in `__eq__` too.

After adding those methods, the body of your loop is still incorrect. The problem line is `graph.addVertex(Node(node1))` specifically the `Node(node1)`. Supposedly that was intended to create a copy of node1, but it actually initializes a new node, where newnode.value is now an instance of Node, not a string. Using type hints and/or explicit type checking helps catch those problems, for example, adding a check for `isinstance(value, str)` to the initialization body.

Replacing those two conditionals from the loop body, the correct version would be:

```py
if node1 not in graph.Nodes:
    graph.addVertex(node1)
if node2 not in graph.Nodes:
    graph.addVertex(node2)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! This does create a unique set however, if you tried to run the getEdges() function, it still reads the Nodes as unique Nodes and doesn't create a dictionary with multiple keys. For example, Alpha is connected to Beta and Hotel however it outputs like: Alpha
{Hotel: 1}
Alpha
{Beta: 1} instead of [Alpha: {Hotel:1}, {Beta:1}]